# How to replace a term with str_replace(), only if it is not part of another word?

Tags: php, file, str-replace

I have a text file like the following:

yyy.txt:

```
line1                     
line2                      
line3line4    
line5line3    
line3
```

Now I want to replace `line3` with `555` in the code below. But I only want to replace the line if `line3` is not part of another word, e.g. `XYline3` or `line3XY`.

I tried to accomplish this with this code:

```
$filename="yyy.txt";
$line="line3";

file_put_contents($filename, str_replace($line , "555",  file_get_contents($filename)));
```

output:

```
line1

line2

555line4

line5555

555
```

As you can see here it also replaced `line3line4` and `line5line3` even though I don't want this.

So how can I change my current code, that it only replaces the search term if it is not part of another word? I'm kinda stuck here and not sure if this is possible with `str_replace()` or if I have to do it in another way.

Comment: You need to use a regex or a more specific `search` string.

Comment: The format of your question is very scattered. Please format it and clarify your exact question.

Comment: And if you think one of the answers here guessed what you are trying to ask, and you want to move on and ask a new question, you should probably accept the helpful answer (with an upvote, too) and explain in your new question how the new question is different from this one. (Proably link here for background, but make the new question standalone so we don't *have* to click through to understand what you are asking.)

Comment: 1) Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to see how you can format your question nicely 2) Since you re-asked the question with the array example, I guess you don't know how you can get the accepted code to work with arrays, *right*? Or is there another reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$line="/\bline3\b/";    
file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace($line , "555",  file_get_contents($filename)));
```

This will replace all words in a sentence, matching `line3`.

To match exactly, use: `/^line3$/m`

Comment: \b is word boundary ... so if a line had "foo line3 bar", the above regex would result in "foo 555 bar"

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Updated!

Answer (score 3):

A regex such as `^line3$` with the `m` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) would work to find only the `line3` line. The `m` makes the `^$` match each line.

https://regex101.com/r/xT7bS3/1

PHP Usage:

```
<?php
$string = 'line1

line2

line3line4

line5line3

line3';
echo preg_replace('/^line3$/m', '555', $string);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/494548

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace(
    "/^line3\s*$/gm" ,
    "555",
    file_get_contents($filename)
));
```

In the regular express, `^` matches start of a line, `line3` matches, well, line 3, `\s*` matches zero or more spaces/tabs, and `$` matches end of the line.  The switches `gm` mean process all matches and treat string as multiline.

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP. `preg_replace` is global by default.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Your data should be cleaner and your question should be more organized, Anyway,

1. Open your text file, and make sure there's a RC character at the
   end of each line, you will get this done by clicking enter at the
   end of each line.
2. Use the following script:

   ```
   $filename="yyy.txt";
   $content = file_get_contents($filename);
   $content =  preg_replace ('/(\r)+line3(\r)+/', "\r555\r" , $content);
   $content =  preg_replace ('/(\n)+line3(\n)+/', "\n555\n" , $content);
   file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace ('/(\s)+line3(\s)+/', "\s555\s" , $content));
   ```

Comment: Why have 3 regexs? `\s` along would find `\n` and `\r` Also no reason to group them, and I don't see a reason to use `\r` in the replacement string, maybe `\n`.

Comment: To ensure a correct behavior whatever was the hidden characters. Note that the passed data is not clean and the characters between lines would be anything!

Comment: `\s` is any whitespace character... `\s stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed.`- http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html Also won't need the grouping.

Comment: However, I wanted to explain to @sammy how comes a new line  in a text file, and what she pasted here would have different hidden characters.

Comment: Why not use a metacharacter that encompasses all characters, a character class, or an `or` grouping? e.g. `\s` or `[\n\r\s]` or `(\s|\n|\r)`. All of which are redundant unless the OP didn't want to match a return character or new line character.

Comment: That was the easiest way to get back the file as it was, if we used Or for example, we would not get back the same hidden character, the goal was to get the file as it was initially replacing only the needed string.

Comment: The first capture group would have the initial character. Your `$content =  preg_replace ('/(\n)+line3(\n)+/', "\r555\r" , $content);` doesn't use the initial value.

Comment: Could you please write it out as a one instruction?! surely expecting White spaces, new lines or RCs, and getting the file back to it's initial state?

Comment: Ah ok, this was a typo. I will fix it

Comment: So you're not getting what I'm saying.. `\s` **is** `\n`, `\r`, or `\h` so your previous two characters would be replaced.